# Should we keep the tag [green-construction]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [green-construction](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-construction) doesn't seem to offer much specificity. It's clearly not about painting buildings green, so "green" in this sense really just means sustainable, which is already implied by the site we're on.

And we already have a [construction](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction) tag. So, should we burninate [green-construction](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-construction)?

Comment: In the industry "green construction" is typically used when talking about sustainability of the materials being used (steel vs timber studs, metal vs asphalt roofs, etc). I do see that "construction" is almost always paired with "green-construction", so I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting this! The tags on this site can do with some cleaning and wiki improvements, so it's great to see people working on this.

I agree that on this site being green/sustainable is almost always implied in a tag, so I also feel that [green-construction](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-construction) basically is a synonym of [construction](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction)

As a moderator I could already merge the tag, but I'd like to wait a bit to see if there are any people who object to this. Meanwhile I already 'officially' proposed that the green-construction tag should be regarded as a synonym (see also https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tags/construction/synonyms).

To quote the StackExchange explanation:

> Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Comment: I was wondering [how long should we wait for objections](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/350/1056) so I made it a question on meta.